# Faster way to operate columns with if conditions

Tags: pandas

I need to operate a column with an IF as shown in my code. It takes quite a time to compute, is there a faster, cleaner way to do this?

For reference, the column "coin" have pairs like "ETH_ARS", "DAI_USD" and so on, that´s why I split it.

```
for i in range(merged.shape[0]):
    x = merged["coin"].iloc[i]
    if x.split("_")[1] == "ARS":
        merged["total"].iloc[i] = (
            merged["price"].iloc[i]
            * merged["amount"].iloc[i]
            / merged["valueUSD"].iloc[i]
        )
    else:
        merged["total"].iloc[i] = merged["price"].iloc[i] * merged["amount"].iloc[i]
```

Comment: Provide a sample of your data please, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: cant because of NDA.

Comment: You can create a sample with fake data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can vectorize your code. The trick here is to set `valueUSD=1` when `coin` column ends with `USD`. After that the operation is the same for all rows: `total = price * amount / valueUSD`.

Setup a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
data = {'coin': ['ETH_ARS', 'DAI_USD'],
        'price': [10, 12],
        'amount': [3, 4],
        'valueUSD': [2, 7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output:
      coin  price  amount  valueUSD
0  ETH_ARS     10       3         2
1  DAI_USD     12       4         7  # <- should be set to 1 for division
```

```
valueUSD = df['valueUSD'].mask(df['coin'].str.split('_').str[1].eq('USD'), other=1)
df['total'] = df['price'] * df['amount'] / valueUSD
print(df)

# Output:
      coin  price  amount  valueUSD  total
0  ETH_ARS     10       3         2   15.0  # = 10 * 3 / 2
1  DAI_USD     12       4         7   48.0  # = 10 * 3 / 1    (7 -> 1)
```

To do that, use [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) and replace `NaN` by 1 instead of the `valueUSD`:

```
>>> valueUSD
0    2
1    1  # 7 -> 1
Name: valueUSD, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @Backtr4ck. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: the thing is it can end with other than USD, like ETH_DAI. So i don´t think this answer would work. I just need to do the division when the coin = ARS.

Comment: Explain what's wrong with my data

Comment: the mask portion, where the .eq("USD") is. What does that do exactly? I need to divide only when the coin ends in _ARS. Can that code portion be adapted to that?

Comment: Done. I changed the line to `valueUSD = merged['valueUSD'].mask(merged['coin'].str.split('_').str[1].ne('ARS'), other=1)` and that did the trick. Thank you.